# C++ newbie trying to use a vector to assign two names from a input file under authors and two formats to format

Tags: c++

I am very new to coding and am stuck on using a vector to print the book information correctly, some books have two author names or two formats, and i am trying to get my program to output them properly, with how my code currently is, it does not print anything after the number of authors.

**C++ Code:**

```
vector<string> authors[4];
vector<string> Format[2];

ifstream infile;
int i;

cout << "please enter the name of the file you wish to input:" << endl;
getline(cin, filename);

infile.open(filename.c_str());

if (!infile) {
       cout << "file not found!!!" << endl;
       exit(0);
}
while (!infile.eof()) {

    

    string numOfcopies;
    getline(infile, numOfcopies);
    cout << "Copies in stock:" << numOfcopies << endl;

    string numOfauthors;
    getline(infile, numOfauthors);
    cout << "Number of authors: " << numOfauthors << endl;

    string authors[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        getline(cin, authors[i]);
     }
    cout << "Book authors:" << authors[4] << endl;
    string numFormats;
    getline(infile, numFormats);
    cout << "Number of formats:" << numFormats << endl;

    string Format[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        getline(cin, Format[i]);
    }
    cout << "Book format:" << Format[2] << endl;

    string NumPages;
    getline(infile, NumPages);
    cout << "Number of Pages:" << NumPages << endl;
```

Comment: It often helps providing a [mcve]. The above is not minimal and it's not reproducible. Shorten it down to the very bit you don't get the hang of.

Answer (score 0):

First problem:

```
vector<string> authors[4];
vector<string> Format[2];
```

You've declared arrays of vectors.  Not vectors of strings.

Also, your inner loop is redeclaring `authors` and `Format` to a different variable.  You need to fix that too.

Better:

```
vector<string> authors;
vector<string> Format;
```

Then to read `numOfauthors` authors:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfauthors; ++i) {
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    authors.push_back(s);
}

cout << "Book authors:"
for (const auto& author : authors) {

    if (i > 0) {cout << ", ";}
    cout << author;
}
cout << endl;
```

Same issue with your `Format` loop as well.

Comment: I've amended by answer to address more bugs I noticed.

Comment: Well, it reads numOfauthors fine, its just everything after that isnt printed, including the rest of my program.

Comment: @og69nova You haven't provided a program. You've provided a snippet. Make it into something that compiles while keeping it minimal.